# Load photos from google drive using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a camera roll component which will load photos from the device, now i want users will have 2 options when they try to select a photo and send it to backend. First is from device and second option is from google drive. How can i approach this ?

Comment: you need a google login to retrieve the token and use the google drive api: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

Comment: i have done this, but how to display photos to UI and select it then upload to my backend ?

Comment: If you have the list of all file there is the downloadUrl property: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files